# Ejecutar un archivo

Tags: c++

Mi pregunta es si se puede ejecutar un archivo mediante su dirección (file path?).

Por ejemplo, quiero ejecutar el archivo que está en "C:\Program Files\Misc\list.txt" y que en efecto se abra el block de notas con el archivo. Así como si yo lo estuviera abriendo manualmente.

Busqué muchísimos tutoriales pero la mayoría eran sobre escribir o leer los archivos, no es lo que necesito creo. Estoy usando Dev-C++ (aunque no tengo problemas en usar Visual Studio 2017).

Saludos.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que la pregunta se ajuste al sitio; podría catalogarse como `basada en opiniones` ... Volviendo al tema, podrías comenzar por [la documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea). Un saludo.

Comment: @Trauma yo no veo la posible respuesta se "base en opiniones". Seguro que se puede hacer sólo hay que explicar cómo, supongo que a través de 'system' o similares... pero como yo no tengo windows... pues no respondo XD

Comment: @Neoniet Basta con saber lo que hay que hacer. Y hay **varias** formas de hacerlo, desde usar la función que indico hasta mirando el registro de windows. Y yo **tampoco** uso windows, llevo +20 años usando linux :-)

Comment: @Neoniet Independientemente de lo anterior, la pregunta no se ajusta al sitio. Primero hay que buscar, investigar, y **cuando se tenga un problema concreto**, preguntar ;-)

Comment: @Trauma, coincido contigo en que tal y como está planteada la pregunta no parece haber habiado una gran labor investigadora previa (es una indirecta DRAUXEN X-D) pero en lo que respecta a lo de "basada en opiniones" ahí creo que no. No puede responderse una opinión, sólo una alternativa... (por cierto un placer coincidir con otro linuxero XDDD yo por ahí ando, desde Debian Potato que fue mi primera distro :-D)

Comment: @Neoniet Bueno, `cierre por multiples alternativas` es otra forma de decir `basado en opiniones` (a mi juicio, al menos). De todas formas, no he votado por cerrarla ... aun. Jejeje ... mi primera Debian fué la `1.3.1 - Bo` ... ni recuerdo el año ya :-)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función **system(**   **)**.

Por ejemplo para abrir un archivo llamado foo.txt que se encuentra en tu escritorio con el bloc de notas deberías de escribir:

```
system("notepad.exe C:\Users\<Tu Usuario>\Desktop\foo.txt");
```

Aún así, según el usuario [Jona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029914/jona) en el [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435994/how-do-i-open-an-exe-from-another-c-exe), el uso de **system()** no es recomendable ya que no es seguro y afecta al rendimiento del programa, por lo que puedes usar **CreateProcess()**, para más información sobre esta función te dejo el link a la documentación de Microsoft tanto en [español](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/175986/info-understanding-createprocess-and-command-line-arguments) cómo en [ingles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa).

Answer (score 2):

Unicamente debes acceder a la funcion

> system();

y dentro de los parametros, entre comillas colocamos la direccion del archivo, o en este caso del ejecutable del programa que deseemos abrir, siempre teniendo en cuenta que requerimos los permisos necesarios para abrir los mismos desde C++.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

//En este caso yo quiero abrir Blender
system("C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\blender.exe");

return 0;
}
```